# Git will not treat a .html file as binary, even though it's marked as such in .gitattributes

Tags: git, diff, gitattributes

I'm trying to get git to mark compiled code as binary so as to clean up diffs.  For the most part this is working, but not for `.html` files.

Here's my `.gitattributes`

```
web/themes/custom/*/css/** -diff
web/themes/custom/*/dist/** -diff
web/themes/custom/*/pattern-lab/** -diff
web/themes/custom/*/pattern-lab/**/*.html -diff
web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/pattern-lab/public/patterns/00-base-global-01-colors-colors/00-base-global-01-colors-colors.html -diff
```

As you can see, those last two lines are my trying to make it work with something more specific.

And here's a diff

```
$ git show b118f56069f96cd9f1c60ca9d8eca1a213aeabc1
diff --git a/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/dist/style.css b/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/dist/style.css
index 2af390be7..9e0570210 100644
Binary files a/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/dist/style.css and b/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/dist/style.css differ
diff --git a/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/dist/style.css.map b/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/dist/style.css.map
index c558df481..1a6ac917c 100644
Binary files a/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/dist/style.css.map and b/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/dist/style.css.map differ
diff --git a/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/pattern-lab/public/latest-change.txt b/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/pattern-lab/public/latest-change.txt
index b8064ad75..cdea372dd 100644
Binary files a/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/pattern-lab/public/latest-change.txt and b/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/pattern-lab/public/latest-change.txt differ
diff --git a/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/pattern-lab/public/patterns/00-base-global-01-colors-colors/00-base-global-01-colors-colors.html b/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/pattern-lab/public/patterns/00-base-global-01-colors-colors/00-base-global-01-colors-colors.html
index 733999083..a9e9ba436 100644
--- a/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/pattern-lab/public/patterns/00-base-global-01-colors-colors/00-base-global-01-colors-colors.html
+++ b/web/themes/custom/columbia_sps/pattern-lab/public/patterns/00-base-global-01-colors-colors/00-base-global-01-colors-colors.html
@@ -45,10 +45,10 @@
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libraries/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css"  media="all" />

     <!-- Pattern Lab base styles. -->
-    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../dist/styleguide-specific.css?cacheBuster=1553203845">
+    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../dist/styleguide-specific.css?cacheBuster=1553539945">

     <!-- Component styles -->
-    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../dist/style.css?1553203845" media="all" />
+    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../dist/style.css?1553539945" media="all" />

     <!-- Drupal-specific usage -->
     <!-- example using symlinking -->
<snip>
```

So it seems to be working for all file types *except* .html, even though I explicitly list that one file in `.gitattributes`.

Why?

Comment: Are there any other `.gitattributes` files in the tree? (eg on linux `find . -name .gitattributes -print`)

Comment: @torek That was totally it!  I had no idea that there could be more of them, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, the issue was that there was a `.gitattributes` file further down in the file system overriding the top level `.gitattributes` file.